# TSQL Dynamic database references

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

4 databases, all in same instance, with same table structure.

I have a complicated view in the "common" database that doesn't reference a specific database and uses `DB_NAME()`.

I was attempting to run a new view from other databases just doing a `SELECT *` from that view in the common database that references the data in it's own db.

My problem is the other databases' views keep the common database as their current `DB_NAME()`.

Is there a way around this?

My goal is to keep only one copy of the TSQL code that I can run from all databases in one common location yet access the data specific to the database it is ran from, with the view in the "common" db acting as a template.

Comment: Create [SYNONYMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/create-synonyms) on the "secondary" databases referecing the view from your "common" database.

Comment: [`Original_DB_Name()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-db-name-transact-sql) may help, depending on how you handle DB connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you can employ a stored procedure instead of a view, something like this could work.

```
create procedure dbswitcher
@whatDB as varchar(5)
as
begin

    /*
        EXECUTION EXAMPLE
        exec dbswitcher 'DB3'
    */
    if @whatDB = 'DB1'
        begin
            select * from DB1..TableA
        end
    if @whatDB = 'DB2'
        begin
            select * from DB2..TableA
        end
    if @whatDB = 'DB3'
        begin
            select * from DB3..TableA
        end
    if @whatDB = 'DB4'
        begin
            select * from DB4..TableA
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to see a scoped common table that is shared parallel across a same server you can do a three part naming (db).(schema).(TableName) and do a union.  Or you can do the black arts of sp_MSforeachdb.

Say I have two tables with the same exact structure on databases Tester and Tester2 respectively.  They merely are just tables that have a PersonId, FirstName, LastName, and CountryID.  All I really want to see is people across dbs but I want to get the reference to the dbname() that I got it from.

```
USE master
GO

Select
  'Tester' AS Environment
,  FirstName
,  LastName
from Tester.dbo.tePerson
union
Select 
  'Tester2'
, FirstName
, LastName
from Tester2.dbo.tePerson

--As far as I know MS warns against the all powerfull sp_MSforeachdb so you use this with knowing that some day MS may blow it up.
DECLARE @Storage table ( DbName varchar(64), FirstName VARCHAR(128), LastName VARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO @Storage
--Essentially this code says use tokenized database[?] only for names I specify like Tester and on this table run this recursive over the table I tell you.
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];  if db_name() like ''%Tester%'' Select db_name(), FirstName, LastName From dbo.tePerson'

Select *
From @Storage
```